# How to apply a bevel filter for each slice of a flex 4 pie chart?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, styling, pie-chart

Only succeeded with applying it around the whole pie chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this finally by applying the filter to each slice and slightly increasing the distanc between the wedges.

`series.explodeRadius=0.01;`

`series.filters = [bevel];`

Answer (score 0):

Convert the segment of chart into a symbol and apply the filter to that on it's own?